# Data Pass from controller to view

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to display the sum of column debit. When I pass data after sum value of the debit column and store it in a variable, I pass the data from controller to my view but laravel says it's undefined. Can anyone help me with this?

View.blade.php

```
<tr>
    <th>Total Debit:</th>
    <td>
        @foreach ($totaldebit as $tdebit)
            {{ $tdebit }}
        @endforeach
    </td>
</tr>
```

UserController.php

```
$tdebit = DB::table('debitemps')->sum('debit');
return view('pages/payments/debit/debit', [
    'workerlists' => $data,
    'debitid' => $id,
    'Empdebitdata' => $dataEmp,
    'totaldebit' => $tdebit
    ]);
```

Comment: Says it is undefined - where?

Comment: `sum` returned a single value, you should not use it with `foreach`.also your view name is not `debit.blade.php`, you must change it to correct value (in your example View)
`

Comment: if i retun sum with single value by using with than how i use the variable in view

Comment: $tdebit = DB::table('debitemps')->sum('debit');
        return view('pages/payments/debit/debit',['workerlists'=>$data,'debitid'=>$id,'Empdebitdata'=>$dataEmp,compact('tdebit')]);

Comment: I solve that thanks for all your support i use wrong file to access the data, know its clear